# Populate Bootstrap modal form fields from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a Bootstrap modal that displays a large form (30+ inputs).

I wrote the following code to populate the first few fields from JSON.

```
$('#seg-detail-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

  var modal = $(this);

  $.get( "includes/segdata.json", function( data ) {
    $('#seg-detail-modal').find("input[name='segCode']").val(data.segCode);
    $('#seg-detail-modal').find("input[name='orgName']").val(data.orgName);
    $('#seg-detail-modal').find("input[name='referenceId']").val(data.referenceId);
  });

});
```

Is there a more efficient way of populating a large form than what I'm doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just iterate through the object properties and match selector to property in that loop.

Something like:

```
$('#seg-detail-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var $inputs = $(this).find(':input');
  $.getJSON("includes/segdata.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $inputs.filter('[name="' + key + '"]').val(val);
    });
  });
});
```

If a property exists that doesn't have a match the selector will just fail quietly